# Windows 10 not showing in boot options

Tags: boot, windows-10, multi-boot

I have recently installed windows 10, and it booted and worked fine.
But i also installed Kubuntu 15.04 and when going into boot options (f12 while booting) only shows linux os as boot option.
Neither does it show in grub. (i installed kubuntu after windows so grub works fine)
So how do i make windows 10 show up in boot options? (windows 8 showed up)

Windows 10 and ubuntu are installed in Legacy since the installation disks wouldn't boot in uefi

Comment: Windows 8+ hibernates instead of shutting down properly, which makes the partition unreadable and so Grub can't recognise it as a bootable system. You'll have to add a grub entry manually so you can boot windows, turn off that setting, run update-grub to add the automatic entry and delete the manual one.
This thread should help: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=209082

Comment: Note: That thread is for a computer that uses legacy boot with an MBR; if yours uses UEFI, the exact solution probably doesn't apply. But the cause of the problem and the general idea of how to fix it should be the same: Boot windows, change setting, run update-grub.

Comment: i can switch between uefi and legacy support.

Comment: There's still too many variables there. Are both Windows and Kubuntu installed in UEFI, both in legacy, or one of each? People have done all of these. As I'm not familiar with UEFI, I can't really help.

Comment: There are good questions on http://www.AskUbuntu.com/ that answer this question

Comment: @GeorgeT i'm posting this because i can't boot into windows. If i could boot into windows, there wouldn't be any problems